# ComponentNotRegisteredException even with registered instance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have an interface `IMyInterface` and I am registering a Moq object for unit testing like this

```
var myMockObject = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
myMockObject.Setup(a => a.MyMethod(It.IsAny<string>()))
 .Returns(new MyResult()
{
    Props1 = "Testing123",
  }).Callback(() =>
                {

                });

builder.RegisterInstance(myMockObject).As<IMyInterface>(); 
var test = container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
```

But I am always getting the following error:

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: 'The
>   requested service 'IMyInterface' has not been registered. To avoid
>   this exception, either register a component to provide the service,
>   check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the
>   ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.'

One thing to note is that I am accessing the AutoFac builder inside a static class. I have made sure that the autofac builder instance is only created once.

UPDATE it looks like I have to call `builder.Build()` after registering the instance. I guess all instances and types have to be registered and after that you call `Build()`. So it's not really possible to register more instances after that.

Comment: You need to register `myMockObject.Object`, right?

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster I still get the same error with the .Object

Comment: If this is truly a **unit** test, then involving Autofac is just a waste of time. You usually have 1 class to test and a few fake classes. You gain nothing by putting the type of the target class into Autofac just so you can resolve it again. Not only is using the `new` keyword quicker to code, it is easier to understand. On the other hand, if this is an **integration** test, using a container may be appropriate.

Comment: I understand. In my case it´s partly integration test and I need to mock out children object´s

Comment: How do you handle cases where you are resolving if you are not using autofac in unit tests. Do you mock the container? @NightOwl888

Comment: See [How not to do dependency injection - configuring the IoC container in unit test projects](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-configuring-the-ioc-container-in-unit-test-projects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not building your `Autofac` container after registering.

```
builder.RegisterInstance(myMockObject).As<IMyInterface>();

// Create the DI container
var container = builder.Build();

var test = container.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
```

Comment: Hi @NightOwl888 , is it not possible to register and instane later on. Calling build is only allowed once.

Comment: That is correct. You have to new up the builder, populate all of the dependencies and mocks, and build the container in *every* test. I wouldn't recommend using a DI container for unit testing as it is usually not worth the extra effort of doing so.

Comment: It´s a bit strange, I think in Unity you don´t need to call build. You can register instances whenever you like.

Comment: Correct. Most containers don't use the builder pattern. It is done this way in Autofac to attempt to prevent people from abusing the container. During normal use you would never expect the container to be updated at runtime. There was an Update method, but it has been [marked obsolete to prevent these bad habits](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811).